# Scroll left into a negative margin area?

Tags: scroll, margin

I have this development site [here](http://starprovisions.com/dev/bacchanalia.html). It is a horizontally scrolling website with the left and right arrows to guide from panel to panel.

The far left panel is a simple image that we currently have hiding a bit with a negative margin (-240px). This is showing the right way when you hit the site but we need to make it so that the left arrow you see on the main screen panel, when clicked, allows the site to glide over to view that far left image in it's entirety. Is this possible?